# EF Regenerate Code Models from Database Change

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm playing around with EF and have a model set up, generated from a database.  The model is code-only, no designers.

I added a field to one of my database tables.

Is there any easy way I can "regenerate" the model code?

I guess if I had used the designers, this would be easier, and I can find info on migrating the opposite way (add a model property and get a migration to update the db), but nothing about how I can propagate changes from the DB through to the model.

I supposed I could do it manually, but that hardly seems ideal...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat - I just read that before posting here... seems to be doing the opposite of what I'm looking for (as noted in the question)?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane - same thing - this really appears to be migrating changes to the db from the model.  Not what I'm looking for, unless I'm missing something very obvious?

Comment: Oh sorry my fault. But why you are doing this way. purpose of migrations is that you controll everything from code. And create migrations so when you deploy you can apply db changes.

Comment: @jdl134679 - is there a particular reason you do not want to flow the changes from the model to the database?

Comment: @jdl134679 Code-first means you code first, and then let the database be updated from your code. So what you're doing isn't code-first :-)

Comment: @Knelis - so the "code first from database" wizard option means create the code from an existing db, then use only the models to udpate the db afterward?  I don't see a "database first" option... thought I had my terminology correct, sorry.

Comment: Apologies @jdl134679 I misread the question. I'm not sure what the solution is in that instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is just delete the auto generated classes from the project and once again generate them. While following this approach only thing we need to make sure that is, we should give the same name for the data model(class name which inherits from DbContext ) as the previous one.

Comment: I'd considered this, but wasn't sure if there was a better way.  I was particular concerned that any tweaks I might later have to make, I'd have to re-tweak upon doing this (I haven't yet had to tweak anything, just trying to think ahead)

Comment: You can still tweak if you just make sure you propagate changes as you go. e.g. if you make changes in the model code, make sure you push them to the database with a migration/initializer before you start tinkering directly with the database. That way you don't get out of synch and if you later make wholesale changes in the database you can just delete your model code and pull it through again. Also, if you want to add functionality to the models take advantage of them being partial classes.

Comment: @Tone I was more worried about tweaks that wouldn't push back to the db - impedance mismatch glue, as it were.  I'm (very) new to EF/ORMs, but had thought I might later run into cases with navigation properties and such where it might be an issue.  However, my entity and domain models _are_ separated, so it may be safe enough to put the mismatch glue in the DTO adapters instead... or perhaps it's all unwarranted worry. I'll work through it though, I feel better about it now than I did an hour ago.

Answer (score 2):

I remember doing something like this a while back ago - its called reverse engineer code first. Basically it looks at the current database and creates the POCO classes for you based on that database. I've done it both when creating a new project as this tutorial suggests: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx

and I've also done it using an older version of this tool:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

In the end, you may find that Jaydeep's method of deleting and starting over is easiest.

Comment: Thanks, this comment from the msdn helps put it in context: _The Code First to Database wizard is designed to generate a starting point set of classes that you can then tweak and modify. If your database schema changes you can either manually edit the classes or perform another reverse engineer to overwrite the classes._ I'll file the tool in the back of my head as well but will probably just go with Jaydeep's for now.